# Unique Device Identifier

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Does each Apple device (iPad/iPhone/iPod) have just one unique identifier for the span of it's use? Will the following code always return that identifier?

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
```

Will Apple allow to use this method in a deployed application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the UDID (uniqueidentifier) is for life, however, not sure if apple are happy you to call that method to retrieve it.

Comment: If you look at the documentation of the property, Apple encourages you to use it if need be.

Comment: all the issue is that I would like to build an application that gives users a free first month, with the help of web services I can make sure that deleting and installing again the function won't cheat the application and get another new free month

Comment: The relevant documentation is http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier — it's official API and Apple suggest a potential use for it ("You may use the UDID, in conjunction with an application-specific user ID, for identifying application-specific data on your server."). As you say, it also clearly explains that the thing is unique and tied to the device.

Comment: Yes! And you also make sure, that everybody who buys an iPad second hand and tries your service will cry a little tear for you :-)

Comment: Apple changed its mind. uniqueIdentifier will be deprecated in iOS 5. [Official rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier) is now "Do not use the uniqueIdentifier property" but instead generate a unique id.

Comment: As of the end of May 2013, apple will reject apps using the Unique Identifier! So no, dont use it

Answer (score 1):

Apple has announced that in May 2013 will start to reject application that use the UDID to track the user behavior

this is an alternative to the UDID:

You can create a category of UIApplication , UIDevice or as you prefere like this (ARC example)

```
@interface UIApplication (utilities)
- (NSString*)getUUID;
@end

@implementation UIApplication (utilities)

- (NSString*)getUUID {

    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    static NSString *uuid = nil;

    // try to get the NSUserDefault identifier if exist
    if (uuid == nil) {

        uuid = [standardUserDefault objectForKey:@"UniversalUniqueIdentifier"];
    }

    // if there is not NSUserDefault identifier generate one and store it
    if (uuid == nil) {

        uuid = UUID ();
        [standardUserDefault setObject:uuid forKey:@"UniversalUniqueIdentifier"];
        [standardUserDefault synchronize];
    }

    return uuid;
}

@end
```

UUID () is this function

```
NSString* UUID () {

    CFUUIDRef uuidRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
    CFStringRef uuidStringRef = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, uuidRef);
    CFRelease(uuidRef);
    return (__bridge NSString *)uuidStringRef;
}
```

this generate an unique identifier stored into the NSUserDefault to be reused whenever the application need it - This identifier will unique related to the application installs not to the device, but can be used for example to take trace about the number devices subscribed the APN service etc...

After that you can use it in this way:

```
    NSString *uuid = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] getUUID];
```